# Unexpected binding to different aura attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have this test case:

```
<aura:application controller="testBinding">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.echo}"/>  
    <aura:attribute name="aaa" type="account" />
    <aura:attribute name="bbb" type="account" />

    <ui:button press="{!c.change}" label="change"/>
    <ui:inputText 
                  value="{!v.aaa.Name}" 
                  label="account a name" />    

        <ui:inputText 
                  value="{!v.bbb.Name}" 
                  label="account b name" />    
</aura:application>
```

Client side controller:

```
({
    change : function(component, event, helper) {
        var aaa = component.get('v.aaa')
        aaa.Name = 'foo'
        component.set('v.aaa', aaa)

        console.log(component.get('v.aaa'))
        console.log(component.get('v.bbb'))
    },
    "echo" : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var setOrder = (response) => {
            var state = response.getState()
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var a = response.getReturnValue()
            var b = response.getReturnValue()
            cmp.set('v.aaa', a)
            cmp.set('v.bbb', b)
        }
        }
    var order = cmp.get("c.getAcc")
    order.setCallback(this, setOrder)
    $A.enqueueAction(order)
}
 })
```

Server side controller:

```
public class testBinding {
    @auraenabled public static account getAcc(){
        return [select name from account limit 1];
    }
}
```

Results:
[image: results]

My expectation is that on change event/click variable `bbb` should remain the same. Is this some weird JS pass by reference behaviour?

Why is it getting updated in JS and not in UI?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as you. Interestingly if you update the second one after updating the first, they will both change to the second one's value in both the ui and the console log.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the internals of how this works, but it appears to be a problem with a pass by reference when getting the response ReturnValue. If you clone the returned object before assigning it to the component attributes, it should work for you.

```
var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()))
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()))
```